# Installing Ubuntu on a specific partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I wanted to switch from Windows 7 to Ubuntu.

I have two partitions, C where my system is, and D where I keep personal files and other stuff I need.

It would be really a disaster if something happened to the stuff on my D drive.

My question is, how can I install Ubuntu on my C partition and format it?

Comment: Please **always backup your important data** before you change partitions or install a new OS.

Answer (score 1):

- Note the C partition (its `size,freespace`) on a paper.
- Boot `ubuntu live cd or usb`.During the installation process slect `Something else` option which allows you to manually select the partition where you are going to install ubuntu.
- Partitions appears on the screen and `select` the right partition by total size and free space you already noted.(Because the partition doesnot appear as `C` during ubuntu installation.)
- Select that partition,right click on it and format it to `ext4 filesystem`.
- Atlast Select the `formatted ext4 partition` for Ubuntu installation.And don't forgot to create a `SWAP` partition.Swap partition size must be `double the RAM size` if the size of the RAM was lesser than 4GB.